# Win+T hotkey with the System account

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

For my needs, I try to run the Windows hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> by a program.
I tried by using keybd_event and SendInput. it works carefree in Win8.1 "Real" OS.

Now, I try the same programs with explorer Shell running with the System account.

```
taskmgr -> kill explorer ->  Psexec -s -i explorer.exe
```

or

```
taskmgr -> kill explorer ->  nircmd.exe elevatecmd runassystem explorer.exe
```

unfortunately it does not work, <kbd>Win</kbd> or <kbd>T</kbd> alone work but not the combination.
I tried also with autohotkey, the nice HotkeyP but whithout success.

I try with System User because I am focus on Win8.1PE which use the system account.
Everything works well enough but the taskbar is locked, disabled at startup
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, hit manually, allows to activate it, same in Real Win8 with explorer running as System.

Some message lines seen with Spy++

```
<00001> 000100A6 P WM_HOTKEY idHotKey:01FB fuModifiers:MOD_WIN'T' [wParam:000001FB lParam:00540008]
<00004> 00010502 P message:0xC02B [Registered:"SHELLHOOK"] wParam:00000004 lParam:00000000
<00005> 00010162 P message:0xC02B [Registered:"SHELLHOOK"] wParam:00000004 lParam:00000000
<00010> 000100DE P message:0xC02B [Registered:"SHELLHOOK"] wParam:00000004 lParam:00000000
<00011> 000100E0 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_LWIN cRepeat:1 ScanCode:5B fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1 [wParam:0000005B lParam:C15B0001]
<00012> 000100E0 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'T' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:14 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1 [wParam:00000054 lParam:C0140001]
<00013> 00010162 P message:0xC02B [Registered:"SHELLHOOK"] wParam:00000004 lParam:000C0D30
<00014> 00010502 P message:0xC02B [Registered:"SHELLHOOK"] wParam:00000004 lParam:000C0D30
<00017> 000100DE P message:0xC02B [Registered:"SHELLHOOK"] wParam:00000004 lParam:000C0D30
```

1 of my basic purebasic sample (I am not a real developper but I try), with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> here, for the test (same issue)

```
keys$ = "R"
handle = 0
For k = 1 To 240 ; wait 1mn max to find the taskbar
  handle=FindWindow_("Shell_TrayWnd ",NULL) ; Retrieves the handle of Shell_TrayWnd class name window 
  If handle<>0 : Break : EndIf
   Sleep_(250)
Next
If handle=0 ; Does Shell_TrayWnd class name window found?
  End 1 ; Nope, so report 1 for failure to type.
Else
  If IsWindow_(handle)=0 ; Does the target window actually exist?
    End 1 ; Nope, so report 1 for failure to type.
  Else
    ; This block gives the target window the focus before typing.
    thread1=GetWindowThreadProcessId_(GetForegroundWindow_(),0)
    thread2=GetWindowThreadProcessId_(handle,0)
    If thread1<>thread2 : AttachThreadInput_(thread1,thread2,#True) : EndIf
    SetForegroundWindow_(handle) ; Target window now has the focus for typing.
    Sleep_(125) ; 1/8 second pause before typing to prevent fast CPU problems.

    keybd_event_(#VK_LWIN,0,#KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0) ; Release WINDOWS key before typing.

    VkKey=VkKeyScanEx_(Asc(keys$),GetKeyboardLayout_(0)) ; Normal key found.
    keybd_event_(#VK_LWIN,0,0,0) ; Hold WINDOWS key
    keybd_event_(VkKey,0,0,0) : keybd_event_(VkKey,0,#KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0)  ; Press the normal key.
    keybd_event_(#VK_LWIN,0,#KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0) ; Release WINDOWS key

    If thread1<>thread2 : AttachThreadInput_(thread1,thread2,#False) : EndIf ; Finished typing to target window!
    End 0
  EndIf
EndIf
```

Comment: It is maybe better to also ask like that. 
To try, How I can post a WM_HOTKEY message with MOD_WIN+T to explorer! Shell_TrayWnd! queue ? or a WM_KEYUP message ?